# Why to study causality, exogenous variation is needed

Tags: econometrics, causality

Someone: "To study causality, you need some exogenous variation, that moves the system"

I wonder why we need the exogenous variation. What's this exogenous variation? I totally forget everything about econometrics, gradually picking it up now.

May I have some intuition behind the relationship between the proof of causality and some exogenous variation?

Comment: Note that you do not _need_ exogenous variation. In some cases it might be necessary, but it is certainly not sufficient. See: https://doi.org/10.1093/rcfs/cfx020